# Installing package CCA

Tags: r

I am trying to install the package CCA (I have R version 4.0.5)

```
install.packages("CCA")
```

Yet when I am doing it, it says that I cannot install the package deSolve

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin18/8.2.0'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/gfortran/lib'
ld: library not found for -lgfortran
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [deSolve.so] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘deSolve’
```

And next I have

```
ERROR: dependency ‘deSolve’ is not available for package ‘fda’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/4.0/Resources/library/fda’
```

Comment: Can't replicate the issue (R 4.1.3). Maybe try updating your packages `update.packages(ask = FALSE)`  before installing a new one? Try installing deSolve directly too may help.

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44660784/error-compiling-r-package-samr-ld-library-not-found-for-lgfortran. Check your fortran version and, if necessary, install it. More information here: https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinaries

Comment: I don't why either why deSolve is required but that's my R is telling me. I did what Adam Quek told me and everything works fine now.Thanks